# Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

| Before move | After move |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before array move] | [image] |

Currently, I am moving items up and down an array with this method:

```
arrayMove(fromIndex, toIndex) {
  var element = this.blueprint.track[fromIndex];

  this.blueprint.track.splice(fromIndex, 1);
  this.blueprint.track.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
},
```

Here are items I'm moving:

```
<li
  v-for="(item, index) in blueprint.track"
  :key="item"
  ref="items"
  class="item card mb-24 position-relative"
>
  <Input
    class="item-title"
    v-model="item.title"
    label="Title"
    ref="title"
    :name="`item-title-${index + 1}`"
    @input="updateBlueprint"
  />
  <Textarea
    class="item-description"
    v-model="item.description"
    label="Description"
    ref="description"
    :name="`item-description-${index + 1}`"
    @input="updateBlueprint"
  />
</li>
```

This works exactly as I want it to. However, since I'm using the whole `item` as the `:key`, I get these warnings every time I move an item:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.
> [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error.

Here is my component:

```
<script>
import { TextareaAutogrowDirective } from 'vue-textarea-autogrow-directive'

export default {
  directives: {
   'autogrow': TextareaAutogrowDirective
  },
  inheritAttrs: true,
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    currentValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit("input", val);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="textarea">
    <label :for="name">{{ label }}</label>
    <textarea
      :name="name"
      v-model="currentValue"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      ref="input"
      v-autogrow
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

To see the `autogrow` directive, you can find that here: https://github.com/wrabit/vue-textarea-autogrow-directive/blob/master/src/VueTextareaAutogrowDirective.js.

How do I get rid of these warnings, and keep it working as expected? I have tried `:key="item.key"`, `:key="index"`, `:key="item.title"` and similar, but none have worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Really? Whole question is about "autogrow" and yet the code of directive for this functionality is not included. What follows is just observations. Textarea component is emitting duplicate `input` event - once from `v-model` and once from direct `@input` listener. `inheritAttrs: true` makes no sense - it is default. Also its usage is strange - why to have a `v-model` and at the same time listen for `@input` events? `:key="index"` is same as not having `key` at all

Comment: @MichalLevý Ok, clearly I don't know what I'm doing, so keep that in mind. Do you have anything constructive regarding my issue?

Comment: @MichalLevý I cleaned it up, so hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: I was trying to be constructive as possible. I told you to add the code of `autogrow` directive, not to remove bunch of (rather useful) comments...

Comment: You can find it here https://github.com/wrabit/vue-textarea-autogrow-directive/blob/master/src/VueTextareaAutogrowDirective.js

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article: https://deepsource.io/blog/key-attribute-vue-js/, I decided to generate unique IDs and assign them to my `items`. Once I did that, and used `:key="item.id"`, everything works as expected.